# Python: use str.ljust with map

Tags: python-2.7

I am revisiting some code I wrote some time ago and noticed I had written my own function to pad a string with whitespace.

My original code:

```
def print_info(people):
    col_widths = [max(len(p[0]) for p in people) + 1, 10, 20]
    rows = [['Name', 'Job', 'Mood']] + [[p[0], p[1], p[2]] for p in people]
    rows = (map(pad_string_right, row, col_widths) for row in rows)
    print '\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in rows)

def pad_string_right(string, length):
    if(len(string) > length):
        raise ValueError
    char_difference = length - len(string)
    return string + (' ' * char_difference)

print_info([("Barry", "plumber", "happy"),
            ("Brian", "butcher", "bored"),
            ("Betty", "singer", "hungry")])
```

I want to replace the *pad_string_right* function with the inbuilt *str.ljust* but can't work out how to fit it in when using map.

Comment: Can't you literally just replace `pad_string_right` with `str.ljust`? As in, where you put `pad_string_right`, put `str.ljust`, and make no other changes?

Comment: Fair enough! I was thinking that `ljust` had to be called on a string. Like `"Barry".ljust(10)` and didn't realise you can use it as `str.ljust("Barry", 10)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally just replace `pad_string_right` with `str.ljust` in your `map`:

```
def print_info(people):
    col_widths = [max(len(p[0]) for p in people) + 1, 10, 20]
    rows = [['Name', 'Job', 'Mood']] + [[p[0], p[1], p[2]] for p in people]
    rows = (map(str.ljust, row, col_widths) for row in rows)
    print '\n'.join(''.join(row) for row in rows)

print_info([("Barry", "plumber", "happy"),
            ("Brian", "butcher", "bored"),
            ("Betty", "singer", "hungry")])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Name  Job       Mood                
Barry plumber   happy               
Brian butcher   bored               
Betty singer    hungry
```